# Reuse Multiple Nodes Between Stages in Jenkin's Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an app that I need to build, test, and deploy on Windows and Linux.

I have 40 slaves where 20 are Linux and 20 are Windows defined by a 'Lin' and 'Win' label respectively.

I begin by allocating two nodes (Linux and Windows). The problem is that I need to use them through multiple stages. However, I have not found a good way to go about doing this.

This code should help illustrate what it is I need to do:

```
pipeline {
agent none

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        parallel (
            "Linux Build": {
                node('Lin') { // Say this allocates 'Jenkins-node-lin1'
                    ...
                }
            },
            "Windows Build": {
                node('Win') { // And this allocates 'Jenkins-node-win1'
                    ...
                }
            }
        )
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            parallel (
                "Linux Test": {
                    node('Lin') { // I need to reuse Jenkins-node-lin1 here 
                        ...
                    }
                },
                "Windows Test": {
                    node('Win') { // And Jenkins-node-win1 here as well
                        ...
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            parallel (
                "Linux Deploy": {
                    node('Lin') { // Same story down here
                        ...
                    }
                },
                "Windows Deploy": {
                    node('Win') { // And this one too
                        ...
                }
            )
        }
    }
} // End stages
}
```

I've tried quite a few 'solutions' but none have worked out for me thus far and to be honest, I'm not sure this functionality is incorporated into Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I think you could do something like (by the way, you are missing your steps{} blocks):

```
def linux_node
def windows_node

pipeline {
agent none

stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
        parallel (
            "Linux Build": {
                node('Lin') { // Say this allocates 'Jenkins-node-lin1'
                    linux_node = env.NODE_NAME
                }
            },
            "Windows Build": {
                node('Win') { // And this allocates 'Jenkins-node-win1'
                    windows_node = env.NODE_NAME
                }
            }
        )
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            parallel (
                "Linux Test": {
                    node(linux_node) { // I need to reuse Jenkins-node-lin1 here 
                        ...
                    }
                },
                "Windows Test": {
                    node(windows_node) { // And Jenkins-node-win1 here as well
                        ...
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            parallel (
                "Linux Deploy": {
                    node(linux_node) { // Same story down here
                        ...
                    }
                },
                "Windows Deploy": {
                    node(windows_node) { // And this one too
                        ...
                }
            )
        }
    }
} // End stages
}
```

I am not sure your reason for requiring affinity to a certain node, but if it is so that certain files are available in the workspace, this does get a little risky doing it this way. There is no guarantee that the same workspace will be used. It USUALLY will be, but there are times when the workspace could change.

The other option is to *stash* your files you need to keep between stages and *unstash* them in the next stage. Then it doesn't matter what agent they end up on. (unless you have some other reason for the node affinity).

Comment: I have since tested something similar to this and it works well. Did you get this working?

Comment: Albeit a while ago, yes, your solution did work for me. Thanks!